# Leaflet animated marker create duplicated markers

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markers

I am using Leaflet with the animated marker plugin. The main idea is to create an animated marker that goes to one place to another and, at the end, create another (**ONE**) animated marker in the same latitude and longitude that goes to another place and remove the first one.

Right now, when the first animation ends it creates **two** animated markers.

Here is a that part of the code:

```
function moveDriverToPassengerLocation(driver, passenger) {

    // Creating the request for google's direction services
    var request = {
        origin: driver.startLocation,
        destination: passenger.startLocation,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    };

    // Sending the request
    directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {

        // Verify if the status is ok for getting the path
        if (status == 'OK') {
            // Decoding the polyline
            var decodedPath = L.PolylineUtil.decode(
                result.routes[0].overview_polyline);

            // Verify if the path has more than one point
            if (decodedPath.length > 1) {
                var line = L.polyline(decodedPath);

                // Creating the new animated marker
                var marker = L.animatedMarker(line.getLatLngs(),
                {
                    distance: 300,
                    interval: 2000,
                    icon: taxiIcon,
                    onEnd: function() {
                        map.removeLayer(this);
                        moveDriverToPassengerDestination(driver, passenger)
                    }
                }).addTo(map);
                marker.id = driver.id;
                marker.startLocation = driver.startLocation;
                driversMarkers.push(marker);
                marker.start();
            }
        }
    });
}

function moveDriverToPassengerDestination(driver, passenger) {
    // Creating the request for google's direction services
    var request = {
        origin: passenger.startLocation,
        destination: passenger.destination,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    };

    // Sending the request
    directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {

        // Verify if the status is ok for getting the path
        if (status == 'OK') {
            // Decoding the polyline
            var decodedPath = L.PolylineUtil.decode(result.routes[0]
                .overview_polyline);

            // Verify if the path has more than one point
            if (decodedPath.length > 1) {
                var line = L.polyline(decodedPath);

                // Creating the new animated marker
                var marker = L.animatedMarker(line.getLatLngs(),
                {
                    distance: 300,
                    interval: 2000,
                    icon: taxiIcon,
                    onEnd: function() {
                        map.removeLayer(this);
                    }
                }).addTo(map);
                marker.id = driver.id;
                marker.startLocation = driver.startLocation;
                driversMarkers.push(marker);
                marker.start();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

**EDIT:**

After a little debugging I found that onEnd function is running twice in the first animated marker and probably in the second marker as well, but I still don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed

```
marker.start();
```

And added this line when I create a marker

```
autoStart: true
```

So, the creation of the marker finally looks like this:

```
var marker = L.animatedMarker(line.getLatLngs(),
{
    distance: 300,
    interval: 2000,
    autoStart: true,
    icon: taxiIcon,
    onEnd: function() {
        map.removeLayer(this);
        driver.isMoving = false;
        addDriverMarker(driver);
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

It solved the problem.